# SQL Server 2008 R2: getdate() returns wrong date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, getdate

We have a table which has a `InsertDate` column that gets its value by calling the `getdate()` function. But there are some records that have weird values like:

```
3879-07-08 11:25:43.947
4500-09-29 11:25:43.983
3258-03-20 16:33:52.493
```

Although these records are old (belongs to 9 months ago), my manager has asked me to find out what has happened in this case.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

This records are not created by individual user and on same day.

Comment: It's pretty impossible without audit tools and all that to "go back in time" and see how data might have happened. The usual suspect when dealing with dates is that somebody used a string with incorrect format - and that the data has been inserted or updated using that.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have a Java application that uses Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver version 3.0 and Java Runtime Environment version 1.7 (JRE 1.7) to connect to a SQL Server database.

If this is the scenario, it may be caused due to JDBC drivers. The fix for that is available at the below link:

[Hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=2652061&kbln=en-us)